# Is it possible to obtain the actual values of a primary composite key with a SQL statement?

Tags: db2

I have a table named F0911 (JD Edwards ERP system) that is in DB2 on an AS400.  This table has a primary key, F0911_PK, which is defined as a composite of seven columns: GLDCT, GLDGJ, GLDOC, GLEXTL, GLJELN, GLKCO and GLLT

I am trying to replicate this table into a BI application and it would go easier if I could obtain the actual values of the primary key, ideally with a statement like:

```
select F0911_PK, [other columns] from F0911 Where ...
```

Is such a thing possible?  I am guessing that the index values have already been calculated and are likely integers.  Is it possible to get at the raw values using a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is a logical construct; there are no "actual values of the primary key", apart from the values in the columns it comprises. If you mean the key values of the index that backs the primary key constraint, they may or may not be a simple concatenation of the binary representation of each column value; in any case these values have no meaning or use outside the physical structure of the index file.